# how to fetch an object by matching an array of foreign keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, foreign-keys, rails-activerecord

I have 2 models: Group and User in my rails app.

Group has many users.

In my app, I would like to use an array of User Ids to check if a Group exists.

I have tried using this method `Group.joins(:users).find_by('users.id' => [1,2,3])`

but this will fetch all the Group objects that contains each User id individually.

What I want to achieve is to get the group object that matches the array of user_ids exactly.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `find` over the `Group` collection (i.e. ActiveRecord::Relation) and compare the array vs `users.ids` of each `Group`, like this:

```
Group.find { |group| group.users.ids == [1,2,3] }
```

Also, I would recommend moving that logic to the `Group` model:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users

  def self.with_users(ids)
    find { | group| group.users.ids == [1,2,3] }
  end
end
```

And then use it like this:

```
Group.with_users([1,2,3])
```